# How can I add a br tag inside of css "after" selector?

Tags: html, css

I am using the css after:: selecter to display texts. What I want to do is simply add a 
 tag before this display. Cant get it to work

```css
H2::after {
    content: " <br>posted by me";
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<H2>Hello</H2>
```

Comment: It is **not** possible to render HTML in pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot add html tags inside `content:""` of pseudo-element.

use `display:block` on the `:after` pseudo-element and you will get the desired result . see below :

```css
H2::after {
    content:"posted by me";
    display:block;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<H2>Hello</H2>
```

let me know if it helps

or you could use JQ if you REALLY want to include HTML tags

```js
$("h2").after("<span style='color:red;font-style:italic'>posted by me</span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<H2>Hello</H2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to break the "::after" onto a new line why not add a "display:block" rule?

```
h2::after{
   content:"posted by me";
   font-size:14px;
   display:block;
}
```